# pandas plot - multiple colorbars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

How can I properly plot 2 colorbars with pandas scatter plots? Right now the first colorbar is duplicated:

https://gist.github.com/denfromufa/45c446690a69265d39dd

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([100,5]),columns='A B C D E'.split())
df.head()


%matplotlib inline
ax1=df.plot(kind='scatter',x='A',y='B',c='C',s=df.D*50,cmap='summer',linewidth=0,sharex=False);
df.plot(ax=ax1,kind='scatter',x='A',y='C',c='D',s=df.B*50,cmap='winter',linewidth=0,sharex=False);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the matplotlib functions directly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd   

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([100,5]),columns='A B C D E'.split())

sc1 = plt.scatter(x=df['A'], y=df['B'], c=df['C'], s=50*df['D'], cmap='summer')
plt.colorbar(sc1)
sc2 = plt.scatter(x=df['A'], y=df['C'], c=df['D'], s=50*df['B'], cmap='winter')
plt.colorbar(sc2)
```

which produces

[image]